# React GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js

I have been working on Apollo Grapghql and come accross a scenario where i had to pass a variable to the query but I am getting an error when i try to do so

```
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $
```

Here is my query

```
let getFilters=
      {
        userPoliciesGet($filter: PolicyFilter) {
          policiesExternal {
              ${this.requestsPayload}
          }
          policiesImported {
              ${this.requestsPayload}
          }
        }
      }
    `
```

and then i am calling this query like

```
import apollo from './client'
apollo.query({
      query: gql`
        ${getFilters}
      `,
      variables: {
        filter: { status: 'ENDED' }
      },
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
    })
```

The ApolloClient is configured correct and works for the rest of the api's.

I dont understand what is wrong with this way, ***if i try to hit this api without any variables, it works fine ,but not when i hit it with the filter varibles***